# Can I run a Steam app with a batch script?

Tags: steam, windows

I have had Steam for a while now and have figured out *a lot* of tricks and shortcuts for the program. There is still one thing I want to do, but can't figure out: I want to run a Steam app with a batch script to circumvent the Steam GUI. The app in question is GameMaker: Studio. If I try to run the app through the executable directly, I get the follwing error:

`GameMaker must be run from within Steam!`

I have attempted to use this script, but it does nothing:

`Steam.exe "%APPPATH%"`

I *could* just make a desktop shortcut using Steam, but I want to know how to do this with some scripting. Any helpful information is appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to, _but_ you have to provide the gameid in the form of a steam uri, not the path to the executable. Something like: `Steam.exe steam://rungameid/12345`

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I was just starting to think that some sort of unique identifier would be needed as opposed to a target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff Mercado mentions above [Steam browser protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) is a possible solution. It's also possible to use it from a webpage or other apps that can open a page in your system's default browser, so it can be great with the command line combined with `explorer "URL"` for example.

One of the problems with this is if you set it to automatically open Steam links by default. The links can do things ranging from installing/launching a game to deleting it, along with a lot more that's not documented either officially in the [Steam Command Line Options](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Steam_.28Windows.29) or unofficially [from data extracted from the Linux version of Steam](https://gist.github.com/davispuh/6600880).

Another option is to use the Steam Command Line Options, as linked to above. It allows you to use more of the commands/etc, and you can do so far easier, so it's actually kind-of more powerful than the browser protocol *but* is not as cross-platform friendly. Of course if you're making a BATch script that doesn't really apply to your situation though ;)